# Is it possible to download ios app before availability date for iTunes connect?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I submitted my app to Apple app store. Now the status has become "ready for sale" and has an availability date at next week. But I want to download that app for testing. Is it possible to download it via my itunes connect account?

Comment: Production App is not for testing. You should have a copy using Development certificate, isn't it ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You need to get promo code for your app (check out iTunes Connect documentation, if you don't know how).

Promo codes can be used to get the app, if it is Ready for Sale, but it is not published on the App Store (by setting release date in future). You can also to you this to give an access to your app, e.g., for some review sites etc.

Answer (score 2):

No not possible. If you can download, anyone can download as before the availability date, you can not found your app on app store. Also, you can change the setting like availability date etc. Then it will be ready for everyone as well as for you.

Comment: if you can down vote you can comment please

Comment: Down voter please comment i want to improve my skill so welcome to you.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on publishing your app!

You got ahead of yourself, but here is the Apple Dev documentation for beta testing:

[Beta Testing your iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1)

and here is the documentation for App Distribution in general:

[App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

You also have third-party options for beta testing such as TestFlight:

[TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

See if you have set the availability date for the next week. Then you can't see your application on iTunes Store. So in this case, there is no chance to download your application.

If you want to download your application for test, then set the current date as availability date, after downloading the application, change the availability date.

Hope this will help.